# Find the most recent Time Stamp of a specific item when there are multiple entries per item

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to document the days a car was cleaned and return specific data about the cleaned car (ie something is broken, location, etc). So, I want each car to report the most recent cleaning by returning the date (or days since if possible). The documentation system reports each cleaning as a separate row in order to know other details like who did it etc. There will be about a hundred reports of each car so I want a smaller quick glance kind of sheet that says car 1, cleaned 12 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

I have a sample sheet I made for [Fleet Vehicle Maintenance](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EV6TC6Fv085es-dxjqo1AEITGBXNzHlPHWak73AY0YI/edit?usp=sharing). You can take the same logic and apply it to your question.

The data is entered using a Google Forms for odometer readings for specific vehicles.

[image]

This form feeds into the Odometer Readings sheet:

[image]

Another sheet groups all the distinct vehicles together and states the most recent Odometer Reading Date.

[image]